# Virtual point of a metric space.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

For a metric space $X$, consider a fixed point $z$. Let $\delta_z(x) = d(z,x)$ denote the distance from a point $x$ to $z$.  Then $\delta_z$ (or, more simply $\delta$) is a function from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ measuring the distance of every point in $X$ from $z$.

This function satisfies

1. $\delta(x)-\delta(y)\leq d(x,y)\leq \delta(x)+\delta(y)$,
2. $\inf_{x\in X}\delta(x)=0$, and
3. $\delta(z)=0.$

Now if we consider a function $u$ satisfying these properties except the third one i.e.

1. $u(a)-u(b)\leq d(a,b)\leq u(a)+u(b)$,
2. $\inf u(X)=0$, but
3. $0\notin u(X)$.

Then we can think of a *virtual point* $z$ which is not actually in $X$. If it existed, then by setting $u(z) = 0$, the function $u$ would measure distance from $z$ to each point in $X$.  Actually it is related to completeness.

We say a metric space has a virtual point if such a function $u:X\to \mathbb R$ exists.  To make it clear let us assume that such a function exists.  Then we can construct a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $0<u(x_n)<1/n$ for each $n$, i.e. $u(x_n)\to 0$ but $u(x_n)$ is never equal to $0$.  Then this sequence $(x_n)$ shall be Cauchy from the first property of $u$.  But it will not be convergent because then $u(x)=0$ for $x=\lim x_n$.  Moreover, we can say, a metric space is complete if and only it has no virtual points.Is there any related link available online on the topic *virtual points and completeness* because I have yet not found one.Secondly,are there any other interesting aspect that I have missed here.

Comment: Your question was very hard to read (there were no spaces at the ends of sentences or after commas, there was no white space to break up the wall of text, and the notation was quite dense.  I have tried to clean it up a little.  Please feel free to revert and/or make your own edits.

Comment: That begin said, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see an actual question here.  Please ping me if you edit your post to include a question, and I will retract my close vote.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry I forgot to complete my question as I was in a little hurry,I did not notice that I have not written the question.I have now made necessary changes.

Comment: You've described yourself a procedure for assigning a Cauchy sequence to each virtual point, and conversely each equivalence class of Cauchy sequences determines a virtual point. So there's no difference between equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences and virtual points.